# Check how many Bytes does my index need to be stored?

Tags: postgresql, index

Let's suppose we have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
 ( 
C_CUSTKEY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
C_NAME CHAR (25),
C_ADDRESS CHAR (40),
C_NATIONKEY INTEGER REFERENCES NATION(N_NATIONKEY),
C_PHONE CHAR (15),
C_ACCTBAL NUMERIC (12,2),
C_MKTSEGMENT CHAR (10),
C_COMMENT CHAR (117)
)
```

as you can see there is a `PRIMARY KEY` on `C_CUSTKEY` attribute.

- How can I check how many bytes do that index need to be stored?

I am using

```
SELECT
    pg_size_pretty (pg_indexes_size('customer'));
```

returning 32MB. Is that correct? Also, I am using `pg_table_size` to check how many Bytes does a materialized view need to be stored.

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's not a script of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_indexes_size` returns the size of *all* indexes on the table.

To get the size of the primary key index alone, you first have to find its name (probably `customer_pkey`). Then you can run

```
SELECT pg_relation_size('customer_pkey');
```